# Please Help Me Out In Finding This 1 small error in the Code

Tags: html, asp.net

Hello Everyone I need help with a lab assignment i am working on there is a small error the professor has put and i just cant find it. The lab has to do with SQL Database. The error is in the sql statement. Please help me find it thank you.

```
// Attach connection string to connection object.
con.ConnectionString = conn;

// Attach the connection object to the command object
cmd.Connection = con;

// Build sql string
String sql =
    "SELECT " +
        "Players.PlayerID, " +
        "Players.TeamID, " +
        "Players.LName, " +
        "Players.FName, " +
        "Players.PNumber, " +
        "Players.BDate " +
    "FROM" +
        "Players " +
    "ORDER BY " +
        "Players.LName Asc, " +
        "Players.FName Asc";

// Add sql to command object
cmd.CommandText = sql;

txtPlayers.Text += "***CommandText: " + cmd.CommandText + "\n";
```

Comment: Assuming you have an environment in which to run this you probably could have found the problem just by reading the error message that came back.

Answer (score 2):

You have no space in the string between `FROM` and `Players`.

You would have found this easier to spot if you had printed the generated SQL to the screen to examine it.